# JS - getElementById with tags

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am trying to shuffle some elements around but the onclick tag gets lost. How can I get the element including the tags?

```
var first = document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML; // I want to keep the onclick tag for this one.
```

---

Here is the rest of the code if you need it

HTML file:

```
<p id="demo"> Start </p>

<p id="demo1" onclick="alert('hello')"> First </p>
<p id="demo2"> Second </p>
<p id="demo3"> Third </p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="temp.js"> </script>

<script> 
    var first = document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML;
    var second = document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML;
    var third = document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML;
    shuffleOptions(first, second, third); 
</script>
```

temp.js file:

```
function shuffleOptions(first, second, third) {
    var options = [first, second, third];
    options.sort(function(a, b){return 0.5 - Math.random(); });
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = options;
}
```

Comment: Instead of 'innerHTML' property, you can user outerHtml.
Try this...

Comment: @NedimHozić It works. Thanks

Comment: Just wanna let you know that those are called "attributes." In HTML it's a good idea to say attribute instead of tag to prevent confusion. Tags usually refers to the element itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function shuffleOptions(first, second, third) {
var options = [first, second, third].sort(function() {
return .5 - Math.random();
});
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = options;
}
```